# Socket.io Client emit old data

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want the button to emit only a new data.

My button set on click with the function below,

```html
function regis() {
  socket.emit('register', 
  {
    'username': $('#regis-username').val(), 
    'password': $('#regis-password').val(), 
    'email': $('#regis-email').val()
  },function () {
     console.log('Regis');
  });
}
```

When I click on it at first time, it emits my data to the server. //This is correct.
So I try second time, it emits my old data to the server and emits my new data to the server. ( 2 times emit in order )
So I try third time, it emits my old data then my second data then my new data. (3 times emit in order)

How can I do to make my button emit only one time with my new data for each click?

Comment: How are firing the function ?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the code that I can see that would cause the client to emit more than once and anything but what is in those elements.

Are there any other places with room for error? 
Maybe as a precaution you can clear the form elements?

```
function regis() {
    socket.emit('register', 
        {
            'username': $('#regis-username').val(), 
            'password': $('#regis-password').val(), 
            'email': $('#regis-email').val()
        },
    function () {
          console.log('Regis');
          $('#regis-username').val('');
          $('#regis-password').val('');
          $('#regis-email').val('');
    });
}
```